# How to use Mongoose queries to filter to the documents that have a specified value inside an array-typed field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I know how to use `Model.findOne` but I wish to use [Mongoose queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for the same task.

How is it possible to do this using Mongoose queries?

So I have this old code:

```
Notification.find(
  {
    subscribers: user.id
  }
)
...
```

and I am working on this alternative code:

```
const r = await Notification.find()
  .where("subscribers")
  .equals(user.id)
...
```

But I don't think `.equals` works for this case since `subscribers` is an array of `ObjectId`s and `user.id` is an `ObjectId`-based string.

I have searched through the official API docs and did not found an answer. There are no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the `Query.prototype.all` method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-all). Now the code looks like this:

```
const r = await Notification.find().where("subscribers").all([user.id]);
...
```